# Avoid rounding of coordinates in pyQgis

Tags: qgis, polygon

If I get the coordinates of a polygon in qgis by

- x = geom.asPolygon()

It rounds off the coordinate from i.e.

-27,200,334.86

to

-2.72003e+07

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663272/double-precision-floating-values-in-python